# How are these two angles the same?

Tags: trigonometry

[[image]

I'm following a youtube tutorial that teaches physics and the video says these two angles are the same, would someone help me understand how they are the same? Thank you!

Comment: Call the smaller right triangle ABC. Say angle A= $\theta$, angle B=90. Then the "other theta" +90+angle C = A+B+C (as the sum of angles of a triangles is 180). Can you see now why the two angles are equal?

Comment: Yeah I can see it now, interesting, I never thought of comparing a triangle with a straight line~

Comment: If the rays of two angles are perpendicular then the angles are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, angle $\theta$ in the bottom-left corner is part of a right triangle, so the remaining angle in that triangle (underneath the $90^\circ$ angle) would be $180^\circ - 90^\circ - \theta=90^\circ-\theta$.

Since $90^\circ - \theta$, the right angle $90^\circ$, and the remaining angle all sit on the same line, they must add up to $180^\circ$, which means the remaining angle is $180^\circ - 90^\circ - (90^\circ - \theta)=\theta$.